# AVAudioSession Won't Play On iOS 7

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

On iOS 6, I have been able to set up an AVAudioSession to play mp3 files.  While running with Base set at iOS 7, this no longer works.  Any ideas why this won't work?  The app never crashes...it just doesn't play the mp3.  I have verified this same code and same URL works on iOS 6 apps.

Errors are:

```
ERROR:     185: Error creating aggregate audio device: 'what'
WARNING:   219: The input device is 0x31; 'AppleHDAEngineInput:1B,0,1,0:1'
WARNING:   223: The output device is 0x28; 'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,1:0'
ERROR:     398: error 'what'
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}
```

The code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];

    if (setCategoryError) { /* handle the error condition */ }

    NSError *activationError = nil;    
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];

    if (activationError) { /* handle the error condition */ }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];   
    [self becomeFirstResponder];    

    NSURL *newURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_entry.articleUrl];
    self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: newURL];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    player.allowsAirPlay = YES;
    player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;    
    player.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview: player.view];
    [self.player setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                               selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                   name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                 object:player];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                               selector:@selector(exitedFullscreen:) 
                                   name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification 
                                 object:player];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                               selector:@selector(playbackStateChanged:) 
                                   name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification 
                                 object:player];
    [player play];

    [super viewDidLoad];   
}
```

Comment: Add a log statement for set Active: `NSError *activationError = nil;
if ([audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError] ) { NSLog(@"Audiosession errore: %@", error) }`

Comment: @rckoenes I just added error and warning message logs to the original post.

Comment: similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104728/itemfailedtoplaytoend-mpmovieplayercontroller-ios7 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088955/ios7-issue-on-playing-mov-file-in-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller. Does your file name have spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```
NSURL *newURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:_entry.articleUrl];
```

instead of

```
NSURL *newURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_entry.articleUrl];
```