# iOS7 issue on Playing mov file in MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios7

I was able to play .mov file using following coding in ios 6.1.3 and below but in iOS7 it closed automatically.

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp1 = [[ MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
if (mp1)
{
    self.moviePlayer= mp1;
    [mp1 release];
    self.moviePlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;

    self.moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    [self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];

    self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

    //Register for the playback finished notification.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer];

    //setup device rotation notification observer
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [self.masterVC presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
    [self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
    [self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:TRUE];

}
```

Using above coding I can able to play .mp4 file in iOS7 and all. Does apple restricted mov files?

Answer (score 1):

I may be having the same issue as you. If you look at your logs, do you get the following error:

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: { 
    kind = 1; 
    new = 2; 
    old = 0;
}
```

The only other idea I have is to use a new class such as AVPlayer or even a third party class to play my media. I don't see any settings that are incorrect in your code nor my code. It is iOS 7 related though.

Comment: I'm also getting the same log in my console. I'm trying using third party player now.

Comment: I've solved my issue by changing the names of the media file I'm playing. This may not be your case, but for me the file name was something like "video one 10.9.13.mov". I changed the name to something without spaces and without the dots i.e. video_one_10_9_13.mov

Comment: Where anyone able to solve this issue, I'getting this _itemFailedToPlayToEnd: { 
    kind = 1; 
    new = 2; 
    old = 0;
} and also I'm getting error = -11828

Comment: make sure that the file you're playing has the ability to stream. You can check this by going to the link on your safari browser and see if a play button shows up. If the play button has a crossed out line, that means you can't stream it. This depends on the server